# project refresh failed: peer not authenticated --intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been battling intellij for a while now, i had a project that i was working on, on a windows system. i recently moved to ubuntu and now opening this projects folder has been giving this gradle error. this is the last few lines in my log file:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:113)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:81)
... 126 more
```

i've been through the similar posts on SO .... no luck. Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse

Comment: i've been through that post actually, seems it's a different issue from mine

Comment: Have you seen the comments below the accepted answer?

Comment: Also, this might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578129/exception-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated This issue has nothing to do with Intellij or Gradle but with the SSL configuration of your client and the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: For this to be a quality question, you need to add a little more context and (verbose) logging output.

Comment: actually i might have found something on the page you posted, working on that at the moment, thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck!