# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated in netbeans

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient-4.0.3 and already added certificate on server. The command is as below :

```
keytool -import -file "C:\Users\apex\Downloads\RootCABangladesh2016.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias "sds certificate"
```

But still I am getting below error.

I have read existing issue saying to add TrustManager (X509TrustManager) but as per my thinking this is not solution.

The exception is as follows :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)   
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at jsonParser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:54)
    at powersms.SendSms.sendSms(SendSms.java:44)
    at powersms.SendSms.run(SendSms.java:32)
```

[I have tried this solution . But this is not working for me .](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795624/6379197)

I have checked the expire date by this command.

```
keytool -list -v -alias "sds certificate" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass "changeit" | grep "Valid from:"
```

But this shows me  :

```
Valid from: Wed Dec 21 16:43:56 BDT 2016 until: Mon Dec 21 16:43:56 BDT 2026
```

I have added jvm parameters .

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
```

Then I go this output :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at jsonParser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:54)
    at powersms.SendSms.sendSms(SendSms.java:44)
    at powersms.SendSms.run(SendSms.java:32)
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Thread-0, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
Thread-0, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-0, called closeSocket()
Thread-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Thread-0, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Buffer Error  Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
JSON ParserError parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0
Json is null
```

Comment: You are correct. It is not a solution. The solution is either to ensure the server's certificate is signed by a recognized CA or else to import it into your truststore. You seem to have done the former *if* the server's certificate was signed by a certificate with the alias "sds certificate".

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: I have imported the certificate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been an issue with `HttpClient` for a while when you try to connect to a secured(i.e. https) URL. There's this class `EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory` in `HttpClient` though, which lets you create `sockets` that accept self-signed certificates. You can try using that as described in the documentation- [EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/javadocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.html)

Not sure if it will solve your problem or not, and it's not very much encouraged to use in production. But you can definitely give it a try to see how it comes up!

Comment: After trying , I will let you know . Thanks for answer .

Comment: Glad that it helped!