# REST assured throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a service that exposes an API which I'd like to test.
I'm running the service on localhost and it has a self-signed certificate.

I added the .p12 file to test/resources and on `@BeforeAll`:

```
    RestAssured
            .config()
            .sslConfig(
                    new SSLConfig().with().trustStoreType("PKCS12").and().relaxedHTTPSValidation().and()
                            .trustStore(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:cert.p12"), "mypassword"));
```

Also added this:

RestAssured.config().sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig().allowAllHostnames());

Although, I'm getting the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Why?

**UPDATE:**
On runtime I can see that `RestAssured.config().getSSLConfig().getTrustStore()` is `null` but how?

**UPDATE 2:** I don't mind that REST assured will trust *all certificates* (security isn't an issue)

Comment: perhaps if's failing to fetch your `cert.12` resource file.

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID, I double checked the file and its password (the file exists and the password is correct)

Comment: it could be an issue with the cert, the fact that your running an SSL locally, etc. checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578129/exception-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID, I edited my question (btw, the certificate isn't expired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it (sort of) by adding `relaxedHTTPSValidation()` like so:

`RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()`

drawback: you have to do that for every HTTP call.