# Kafka zookeeper "Error getting peer certificates", "peer not authenticated"

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, certificate, apache-zookeeper

I am getting this error on the 3 zookeeper pods that I have installed on an openshift cluster:

```
2022-05-09 13:53:40,361 ERROR Error getting peer certificates (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory) [nioEventLoopGroup-7-1]
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:556)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory$CertificateVerifier.operationComplete(NettyServerCnxnFactory.java:403)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1817)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccessIfStillHandshaking(SslHandler.java:1800)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:1028)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1458)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1290)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1337)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578129/exception-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated

Comment: When I do the command it shows that my keystore contains 1 entry so I guess it is not the same error